# getting value generated from method in php

Tags: php, methods, return-value

i have an question about getting value of method

```
custom_get_post_attachments(get_the_ID(), $__width, $__height, get_the_title())
```

This code generates html code (`<img src="...".....>`)

if i echo the method it will display the picture, i dont need to display.

I need to get that generated html code. how can i do it without displaying the picture?

Thanks

Comment: change the `echo` to `return`

Comment: same thing.. displaying the picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want the HTML to be evaluated, then you need to escape it.

```
echo htmlentities(custom_get_post_attachments(get_the_ID(), $__width, $__height, get_the_title()));
```